# Does anyone know how to secure Port Mapper?

Tags: security, centos, hosting, centos7, vps

I recently got the message from my hoster that my portmapper is not secured!
What can I do about this?

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s! 192.168.0.0/24  --dport 111 -j DROP
```

I already tried this code but I get the message that the IP is a bad argument.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper syntax is:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! -s 192.168.0.0/24  --dport 111 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using any sort of NFS services, just disable the service entirely. Best to kill any service you're not using.

```
# systemctl stop rpcbind

# systemctl disable rpcbind

# systemctl mask rpcbind

# systemctl stop rpcbind.socket

# systemctl disable rpcbind.socket
```

Comment: It even better - remove it!